# How to scatter plot with each dimension having its own color

Tags: python, visualization, matplotlib

I want to get insight for some values. I have two vectors of 300 dimensions, and want to compare them coordinate by coordinate. So I thought to plot each point with a different color, but the color for a dimension to be the same so that I would know which coordinates are lying where.

I have the below code, which I modeled on some results at stackoverflow.

```
colors = itertools.cycle(["r", "g", "b"])

for d_in in inp_samples:
    clr = next(colors)
    plt.scatter(len(inp_samples), d_in, c=clr)

colors = itertools.cycle(["r", "g", "b"])

for d_out in out_samples:
    clr = next(colors)
    plt.scatter(len(out_samples), d_out, c=clr)
```

But the plot I am getting is very weird. I was expecting it would be scattered but it is something like this:

[image: plot of the two vectors]

I also tried this:

```
colors = cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, 300))

for d_in, d_out, c in zip(inp_samples, out_samples, colors):
    plt.scatter(len(inp_samples), d_in, c=c)
    plt.scatter(len(out_samples), d_out, c=c)
```

[image]

Can anyone help in understanding what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What about a line plot where x coordinate is dimension number (1-300) and y is the vectors value. Seems easier to compare to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `scatter` in `Matplotlib`, the first two arguments must be the $x$ and $y$ values that you want to combine. In your code, the first value ($x$) is `len(inp_samples)` (or `len(out_samples)`) which is the number 300, so all your points line on the $x=300$ vertical line.

In order to combine the `inp_samples` with the `out_samples`, I too would recommend using `zip`, as in your second sample of code. Just replace

```
plt.scatter(len(inp_samples), d_in, c=c)
plt.scatter(len(out_samples), d_out, c=c)
```

with

```
plt.scatter(d_in, d_out, c=c)
```

(and see if it works).

**Edit**

> So I thought to plot each point with a different color, but the color for a dimension to be same, so that i would know, which dimensional points are lying where.

In a scatter plot, there is no need for any special colouring -- by two values forming one pair of $(x_i,y_i)$, it is already given which point belongs to which.

You could also try to plot $(i,x_i)$ and $(i,y_i)$ in the same plot. In this case, points above each other belong together and you still don't need any special colouring.

```
colors = itertools.cycle(["r", "g", "b"])
for i in range(300):
    clr = next(colors)
    plt.scatter(i, d_in[i], c=clr)
    plt.scatter(i, d_out[i], c=clr)
```

Comment: the plot now looks like a linear line.

Comment: Maybe your two vectors are in a linear (or affine) relationship?! You could print the first 10 or 20 values of each and inspect the numbers by eye how they relate.

Comment: Let me explain about the vectors, the two vectors v_in and v_out, v_in is a the original vector, and v_out is the transformed vector, and on v_out i have done some operation, now I want to know know, by how much distance a dimension of v_in and v_out are far or close to each other. There should be a linear relationship but, I want to see each dimension in space, and not what the relationship is.

Comment: Then perhaps try your 2nd code with my suggestion and a new colormap, e.g. `'BrBG'` or a sequential one: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html You could also try plotting the difference: `plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, 300), np.subtract(v_out, v_in), 'bx')`.

Comment: It worked pretty well.